# Trying to show the selected option from an autocomplete input select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the option that has been selected in an autocompleting input select. I'm using the autocomplete jQuery plugin.

This is the code:

```
$('#autocomplete_name').change(function(){
   $('#').append($('#autocomplete_name').val()); 
});
```

But when i select an option it shows the piece of text I have written in the input select, not the selected option.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI autocomplete plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is the plugin originally created by Joern Zaeffere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#API_Documentation)!

Something like:

```
$('#autocomplete_name').result(function(event, item) {
   $('#').append(item); 
});
```